# JavaScript Array CSV Parsing and sorting and reorder by a position

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, csv, multidimensional-array

I have an array that is X in length, for this example it is 8. Each position is a CSV with 3 values. I am trying to sort it by the 3rd value in the csv.

My Array

```
array[0] = "1,17,28";
array[1] = "2,1,5";
array[2] = "3,37,48";
array[3] = "4,9,15";
array[4] = "5,4,14";
array[5] = "6,6,17";
array[6] = "7,99,110";
array[7] = "8,5,16";
```

How the new array should look after its been sorted into:

```
newArray[0] = "2,1,5";
newArray[1] = "5,4,14";
newArray[2] = "4,9,15";
newArray[3] = "8,5,16";
newArray[4] = "6,6,17";
newArray[5] = "1,17,28";
newArray[6] = "3,37,48";
newArray[7] = "7,99,110";
```

I have completely destroyed my work space trying to get this one working.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for this,

```
var arr = [
    '1,17,28',
    '2,1,5',
    '3,37,48',
    '4,9,15',
    '5,4,14',
    '6,6,17',
    '7,99,110',
    '8,5,16'
];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var x = a.split(',')[2];
  var y = b.split(',')[2];
  return x - y;
});
// Returns ["2,1,5", "5,4,14", "4,9,15", "8,5,16", "6,6,17", "1,17,28", "3,37,48", "7,99,110"]
```

**Edit:**

Just an extra if you want to keep your old array untouched. (ES6 syntax)

```
[...arr].sort(function(a, b) {
  var x = a.split(',')[2];
  var y = b.split(',')[2];
  return x - y;
});
```

Comment: Also, if you want to leave the old array untouched and create a new one, simply add `var newArray = arr.slice(0).sort...` to the above.

Comment: @DawsonToth I edited my answer to support that as well. But yeah, he could also do it with slice..

Answer (score 0):

I would first precompute an array consisting of the third number of each input element; let's call this the "array of thirds". Then you can generate an array representing the index sequence of the same length as the input array, and sort it according to the array of thirds. Finally, you can map the resulting sorted index sequence back to the input array to sort it.

```js
array = [
 '1,17,28',
 '2,1,5',
 '3,37,48',
 '4,9,15',
 '5,4,14',
 '6,6,17',
 '7,99,110',
 '8,5,16'
];

var e3 = array.map(e => Number(e.split(',')[2]));
var newArray = Array.from(array.keys()).sort((a,b) => e3[a]-e3[b]).map(i => array[i]);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You're missing braces in your function calls, and a `return`. Past that, I don't believe the pre-computation helps at all, as it just introduces another iteration over the array, and an additional array stored in memory. There's a lot of complexity and overhead in your implementation which can be avoided.

Comment: @DawsonToth I was trying to avoid the redundancy of the repeated `.split(',')[2]` calls (and subsequent type conversion from string to number on the subtraction) that would otherwise be incurred under the simpler approach during the sort operation. I agree the necessary code turned out to be more involved and complex than one would hope, but this approach could provide performance savings. Imagine if the CSV strings were extremely long with many fields, and if the input array was extremely long as well. I think my solution is not as bad as it looks.